# working of if else in c++ language

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
int n;
cin >> n;
if( 1<=n<=9)
    {
    switch(n)
        {
    case 1:cout<<"one"; break;
    case 2:cout<<"two"; break;
    case 3:cout<<"three"; break;
    case 4:cout<<"four" ;break;
    case 5:cout<<"five" ;break;
    case 6:cout<<"six" ;break;
    case 7:cout<<"seven"; break;
    case 8:cout<<"eight" ;break;
    case 9:cout <<"nine";

    }
  }
  else
    { cout<<"greater than nine"; }

}
```

the above code when i am running (or)compiling my else statement is not working 
for example if i am giving a number like 44 it is not displaying the statement in else that it is grater than nine  but the if case is working nicely.

Comment: Your if condition is not properly specified.

Comment: The expression `1<=n<=9` is equal to `(1 <= n) <= 9`, which means you compare a boolean value (the result of `1 <= n`) with a number.

Comment: `1<=n<=9` is not the correct way to specify multiple boolean conditions. You need `&&` like in most languages.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: can you tell me where to correct my if condition@AnonMail

Comment: where you have "if (1 <= n <= 9)", you need to change it to something that will actually do what you want.

Comment: "1 <= n <= 9" is equivalent to "(1 <= n) <= 9". if n = 44, then first we evaluate (1 <= 44), which evaluates to 1, so then we evaluate 1 <= 9, which evaluates to 1.

Comment: ya i understood now , i am new to programming so i got confused

Comment: Your condition should be like this
if (n >= 1 && n <= 9)

if you'are new with programming language and you don't know how to properly make a  condition you can use  this link / web site to learn 
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html
This lesson will help you to learn how to make a condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with your `if` condition.

It should be like this:

```
if (n >= 1 && n <= 9)
```

As it is now, it means

```
if ((1 <= n) <= 9)
```

Which will always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the condition to

```
if (1<=n && n<=9)
```

Comment: you made a mistake in your condition it's should be 
if (n >= 1 && n <= 9)

Comment: `n >= 1` and `1 <= n` are equivalent. The latter condition might be more readable, because it resembles the mathematical form. `1<=n && n<=9` requires *looking* at it to understand, while `n >= 1 && n <= 9` requires *reading*. The readability difference is small and, I suspect, subjective.

Comment: @Esperadoce There's nothing wrong with the condition in this answer.

Comment: I was just showing how to write the conditions properly. Making it better or more readable was not my intention.

Comment: @Blastfurnace regarding Nikhil Sai question it's a false answer